# Automating user creation for AWS transfer family or secrets manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I created a sftp server to upload files to S3, i have setup ssh authentication and username/password for the server.

Now i want to automate the process of creating users for the server using a lambda function, either by automating the secrets manager part or the aws transfer family user, is there a way to do this or what i am looking for is not yet possible

Comment: You can do this using cloudformation or terraform.

Answer (score 0):

Java example using the AWS transfer family SDK:

```
public byte[] createUser(String sftpBaseFolderPath, String username) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, JSchException {
    CreateUserRequest createUserRequest = new CreateUserRequest();
    createUserRequest.setServerId(serverId);
    createUserRequest.setHomeDirectoryType("LOGICAL");
    createUserRequest.setRole(userRoleArn);
    createUserRequest.setUserName(username);
    List<HomeDirectoryMapEntry> mapEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    HomeDirectoryMapEntry homeDirectoryMapEntry = new HomeDirectoryMapEntry();
    homeDirectoryMapEntry.setEntry("/");
    homeDirectoryMapEntry.setTarget(sftpBaseFolderPath);
    mapEntries.add(homeDirectoryMapEntry);
    createUserRequest.setHomeDirectoryMappings(mapEntries);

    KeyPair keyPair = KeyPair.genKeyPair(new JSch(), KeyPair.RSA, 2048);
    ByteArrayOutputStream privateKey = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStream publicKey = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    keyPair.writePrivateKey(privateKey);
    keyPair.writePublicKey(publicKey, "Key description/comment");
    privateKey.close();
    publicKey.close();

    createUserRequest.setSshPublicKeyBody(publicKey.toString());
    transferClient.createUser(createUserRequest);

    return privateKey.toByteArray();
}
```

Transfer client initialization will be something like this:

```
public AWSStaticCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {
    return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
}

public void initTransferClient() {
    this.transferClient = AWSTransferClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider())
            .withRegion(Regions.fromName(region))
            .build();
}
```

SDK version

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-transfer</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.173</version>
</dependency>
```